# How do I configure prettier to format YAML files to indent the list-items with zero space indent

Tags: yaml, prettier

When I run `npx prettier --write pipeline.yml`, it formats all child lines including dashes (`-`) with 2 space indents from the parent lines, like below:

```
resources:
  - name: concourse-examples
    type: git
    icon: github
    check_every: 30m
    source:
      uri: https://github.com/concourse/examples

jobs:
  - name: set-self
    public: true
    plan:
      - get: concourse-examples
        trigger: true
      - set_pipeline: self
        file: concourse-examples/pipelines/set-pipelines.yml
```

I want all child lines, except the ones start with dashes (`-`), to be indented with 2 spaces from their parent lines, like below:

```
resources:
- name: concourse-examples
  type: git
  icon: github
  check_every: 30m
  source:
    uri: https://github.com/concourse/examples

jobs:
- name: set-self
  public: true
  plan:
  - get: concourse-examples
    trigger: true
  - set_pipeline: self
    file: concourse-examples/pipelines/set-pipelines.yml
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8):

[You can't](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/9355). Quoting the [option philosophy](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html):

> Prettier is not a kitchen-sink code formatter that attempts to print your code in any way you wish. It is *opinionated*.

Comment: Well, it is not the way we want to use. This format is very common for YAML. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is to have prettier ignore all yml files by creating a `.prettierignore` file and adding the following to it...

```
*.yml
```

More info: https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html